# working with nested views?

Tags: android, android-layout

ok i've tried several different configurations. 
this keeps crashing and i can't see why?
here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   <WebView
      android:id="@+id/webview2"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 <RelativeLayout>    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Video 1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/one"
        android:text="Video 2" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/two"
        android:text="Video 3" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your code is either really TINY or missing. =P

Comment: lol@prolink...not sure what happened, i think the admins were reformatting it for me.

Comment: Yeah, it is fixed now. I believe Adinia has a good answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your RelativeLayout have no dimensions; try replacing with this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**Edit:**
Your buttons were not shown because the WebView was filling the screen, even if you set its hight as to wrap the content (usually, the content is larger than the screen). So, as your node parent was a LinearLayout, you should have also seted the weight of the WebView and of the RelativeLayer.
Also, you have seted your two and three buttons to appear at the left of your first button, which was draw at only 10dip of the left margin! :)

So, here is a refactoring of your code, using only a RelativeLayer(there is no need to put it inside a LinearLayout):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <WebView
      android:id="@+id/webview2"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_above="@+id/one"/>   
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Video 1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one"
        android:text="Video 2" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/two"
        android:text="Video 3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ok I gave the relative tag dimensions and that stops it from crashing but my buttons still don't show up?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an working code and explanations, there were more logic problems with your code :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing a closing tag ">" for your Linear Layout.

Comment: I agree with Kingpin, it does appear that you are missing a closing ">" for your linear layout, unless that was left out of the paste on accident.

Comment: yeah it is missing in this example but i assure you it's there in my IDE.